# Votes Cast record in profile is wrong for low reputation users

Tags: bug, voting

When I downvote, it says

> Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 125
>   reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post
>   score.

But when I check my profile, I cannot find the questions/answers I downvoted.

Answer (score 10):

That's because you haven't downvoted the post.  You've provided feedback (in a form separate from traditional voting), but you are unable to actually downvote until you have 125 rep.

Comment: Then how do I check the recorded downvote?

Comment: @netok:  You can't; there is no recorded downvote.  It goes into a bucket with other anonymous feedback, but since you don't have the rep, it doesn't impact the score of whatever you downvoted.

Comment: @netok Again, you did not downvote the post.  You need to have 125 rep to downvote.  Anonymous user feedback is recorded in the data explorer, but the feedback is anonymized, so you wouldn't be able to see what feedback you have provided.

Comment: Then maybe the message could be improved by saying it is recorded "anonymously".

Comment: @netok It's anonymized when shown publicly, that doesn't mean it's stored anonymously.

Comment: @Servy Then it could be improved by saying "**Feedback** by those with less than 125 reputation are recorded".

Comment: Netok is right in that the message is confusing/misleading. Something like "Votes cast by those with less than 125 reputation do not count as votes, but rather as feedback that is available anonymously in the Stack Exchange Data Explorer" would be much clearer.

Comment: @Servy And isn't it strange that "it's not stored anonymously" but "you wouldn't be able to see what feedback you have provided"?

Comment: @netok The data isn't stored anyonymously, because otherwise you would be able to sit and click the downvote button repeatedly, providing an unlimited amount of "feedback". If it is associated with your account, it can only be applied once. This feedback is used internally by many different processes, but no, it is not available for you to review.